# How to reduce FootPrints of gsoap generated files mainly soapC.c

Tags: gsoap

I am generating .c and .h files for a web-service application using gsoap 2.8.14 to be used in my application. But the client for whom i am working wants the final application binary to be of lesser footprint. while compiling these generated files soapC.o is having size of 6.5M.

Is there any way by which i can reduce the size of this object file? I have already tried -DWITH_LEANER and DWITH_LEAN option given in soapdocs but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DWITH_NOIDREF. Using it, my soapC.o was 4.1MB.